# Does Ubuntu One Re-load a file after renaming it?

Tags: ubuntu-one, upload

I write countless drafts of folders but sometimes I want to change the title of a doc - the content of which hasn't been altered.

Does U1 reload the entire word doc or does it just rename it?
Basically can it tell the difference between a changed file and a renamed file?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't re-upload the entire contents if the contents are the same. It handles file moves correctly, whether it is a rename, or moving it into a sub-folder.